# How to emulate XMLHttpRequest client using PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm looking for an example how to emulate XMLHttpRequest client using PHP.

In other words, send the request over HTTP POST message, and receive and process the callback message.

Comment: @tputkonen: sorry do you want to post some data from your server to another server **OR** to build an ajax system?

Comment: I just want to be able to send the request and receive the callback answer.

Comment: @tputkonen: so you want your PHP script to send data to a webserver? right ?

Comment: @tputkonen: you should edit your question and remove `XMLHttpRequest` reference it's kind of confusing and just say you wanna make some POST to another server

Comment: Do you want the request to look like it came from an AJAX request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

server.php:

```
<?php var_dump($_POST);
```

client.html:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>omg</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $.post(
          "server.php"
        , {omg: "wtf"}
        , function (data) { alert(data); }
      );
  });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

**edit**: ok, so it's http client written in PHP!

```
<?php

$r = new HTTPRequest("server.php", HTTP_METH_POST);
$r->addPostFields(array('omg' => 'wtf'));
$r->send();
var_dump($r->getResponseCode());
var_dump($r->getResponseBody());
```

Comment: @just somebody: +1 really like the nice snippet. if you add the cdb of google for jquery I would be really happy. http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: I want to implement the client using PHP, not javascript.

Comment: Yup nice snippet. Would be better to add a <pre> to the body and then $('pre').append(data); inside the callback function.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to 'really' simulate an AJAX request, you should, together with all of the above solutions, consider sending [this header](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax) with your request:

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

(check the manuals to the solutions how to set custom headers). Prototype, jQuery, mootools and the such all send this header when they request data via AJAX.

Answer (score 6):

you can use [curl](http://us.php.net/curl) for that purpose

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// set the post 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array( 'foo' => 'bar'));

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest method would be the command line tool `curl`, especially if you have a sample of the data you want to post.